# PostrgeSQL 9.1 Certificate Authentication: how to get certificate common name of client?

Tags: postgresql

I am using [Certificate Authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-CERT) for clients on a PostgreSQL 9.1 database server. Several certificate common names are mapped to a single database user in [pg_ident.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-username-maps.html).

I do not want to create a database user for each certificate because it is easier to manage accepted certificates with pg_ident.conf. But now I need some query to map a backend process to the common name used for the connection. Is there a way to get the common name (CN field) of the certificate with which a user connected to the database?

**EDIT**

Thanks [araqnid](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/680/araqnid) for pointing me at the [sslinfo](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sslinfo.html) extension ([source](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/sslinfo_8c_source.html)). The function [ssl_client_dn_field('CN')](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/sslinfo_8c.html#ac6bd06220c68c034b2d6a4d220acc9b1) provides exactly the information I need.
But the sslinfo functions work only for the connection/backend of the current session, I would rather need this information for other connections/backends (query it by backend process id).

The sslinfo extension uses the global variable [MyProcPort](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/miscadmin_8h.html#a12cbc96f18dc4e20103daae3a402d9f6) (defined in [globals.c](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/globals_8c_source.html)) of type [struct Port*](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/structPort.html) to get the required SSL information.
Maybe someone can give me a hint how the `MyProcPort` variable of other backends could be accessed in an extension (aka contrib module).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the extension `sslinfo`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sslinfo.html

This will give you the `ssl_client_dn` function for the full subject name, or I believe you can do `ssl_client_dn_field('CN')` to extract just the common name.

Comment: Doesn't this happen too late? These look like PostgreSQL functions that you can only run once you've been able to connect. The `pg_ident.conf` doc doesn't seem to say anything about running functions.

Comment: "Is there a way to get the common name (CN field) of the certificate with which a user connected to the database?" - this sounds to me like something being done *after* connecting. Although it might be an issue that the information can only be fetched for the *current* connection, not any arbitrary one.

Comment: Yes, sorry, of course, after connecting, but before authenticating and having access to `SELECT ssl_client_dn_field('CN')` and so on.

Comment: @Bruno tbh I'm not sure we can really tell what the OP needs. do stored functions need this value to save as auditing data? I got the impression that he'd already set up `pg_ident.conf` to allow the correct set of users to connect, but wanted to be able to distinguish them later without mapping them each to a different database user.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that he wanted to implement the mapping using data in the database itself, instead of fixing it in `pg_ident.conf`, to have something more dynamic. I think your interpretation makes more sense indeed, sorry.

Comment: @araqnid @Bruno: yes, I have my accepted certs in pg_ident.conf, I **don't need** to get this somehow more dynamic. But it would be great to map _any_ backend to the certificate used for the connection (for auditing/monitoring). The `sslinfo` module just offers this information for the current connection and not for other connections.

Comment: @tscho unfortunately, afaik this information isn't put into shared memory in the way that the information in `pg_stat_activity` is, so the other processes can't access it.

Comment: @araqnid: thanks for your help! Accepting this as answer even if it's not exactly what I was looking for. The problem is that I cannot control client code and just insert SSL information to some table upon connection. Actually my problem would be a nice use case for logon triggers, but looks like this is not gonna happen soon...